# How to figure out if running in Mono runtime

Tags: .net, mono

I am developing a class library that will be used in both Unix and Windows.

I had a case where Mono's System.Web.HttpClient adds an unwanted header (that .NET Windows does not). But I found a workaround that I can use to prevent side effect of Mono runtime.

To do that **I need to find out if the binary is running on Mono runtime** and I can simply add an `if` statement and distribute my DLL afterwards.

Is there such flag / function to figure that out? Thanks.

Comment: I read somewhere you can use Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime") to check. I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it though! - I also found this link which might be helpful http://mono.wikia.com/wiki/Detecting_the_execution_platform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reflection to check if the Mono.Runtime type is defined. Like this:

```
Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime")
```

The [mono project FAQ](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ%3a_Technical) recommends this method to detect if you are running in mono

Good luck!